What methods can I use to pinpoint my own stylistic choices?
I will admit that I am years out of practice in consistent writing on a personal, professional and academic level. Even even when that wasn't the case, I have always had difficulty understanding what specific elements of my writing created appeal for reading.
In my experience as a "professional" at university, most of my critiques centered around wordiness and concrete thought presentation but practices I excelled in were not really focused on. I minored in journalism and spent time working as an on air host for local radio for about two years, which allowed me to willfully move away from exercising the skills needed to be a more clear and concise writer.
My fiction writing has come to a grinding halt. I am trying to make an effort to create specific, task oriented goals that facilitate strengthening my natural abilities, hardening my technical capabilities and reengaging my creative mind. That said, while my writing has always received positive feedback and i did take pride in that validation when it came, I never allowed myself the opportunity to earnestly pursue development.
I basically just hoped that flowery language would propel me forward. I would love to be able to purposefully employ skills I have intentionally honed to create creative nonfiction/fiction pieces with thematic purpose like someone who spent money on an education in rhetorical arts.
Does anyone have suggestions for exercises, tools, or lessons that serve the purpose of identifying the strongest elements of my writing and making them technically better?

Can you first rephrase the Question title so it matters?

Both the Question title and your detailed exposition seem to me far from clear.
Did you not notice, no-one here could have suggestions for exercises, tools, or lessons identifying the strongest elements of your writing unless either every Answer was based solely on the Question title and Exposition here, or you Posted several examples of your writing?
If you've always had difficulty understanding what specific elements of your writing created appeal, how do you know  any elements worked?
Why is 'professional' at university written with scare quotes?
When critiques ignored practices you excelled in, which practices were those? How does that equate to your writing always receiving positive feedback?
How could journalism for local radio allow you to move away from exercising the skills needed to be a more clear and concise writer, 'willfully' or not?
What tells you your fiction writing has come to a halt? What happens if you literally take up a pen or sit at a keyboard and write for an hour or two without pause, even if what you write is nothing more than 'blank, blank and blankety blank…'
Do you truly see no difference between 'making…' and 'trying to make…' an effort?
Either way, can you say what goal-setting has to do with writing?
When you hoped flowery language would propel you forward, how did that translate into reality? Why would the same not apply equally to everyone else?
Speaking of flowery language at its most basic, why not reverse that and look again at how you would love to be able to purposefully employ skills intentionally honed to create creative nonfiction/fiction pieces with thematic purpose like someone who spent money on an education in rhetorical arts?
Many might disagree and to me, that looks like a fine example of flowery language employed as pure flummery.

The technique for identifying strong and effective writing is called critical reading.  It’s also the same technique used for identifying ineffectual writing.
Learning critical reading skills can be accomplished by reading pieces similar to what you want to write and reflecting on why you find them to be effective or ineffective. This reading both well written exemplars and less well written pieces.
Its in the difference between well written pieces and poorly written pieces that we can mostly easily see how our own writing decisions impact our work.
That said, the hardest pieces to learn from are those written by extraordinary writers. This is because the skill they employ results in nuanced and subtle writing.  For example, as much as I enjoy reading Kazuo Ishigoru and Anthony Doerr, deconstructing their pieces doesn’t teach me as much as reading Stephen King or Brandon Sanderson.
I find I learn the most deconstructing other writers I meet in local writing groups and in online courses offered by UCLA extension and Gotham Writers. For some reason, it was easier for me to see why someone else’s writing is boring or confusing that it is to notice it in my own. Once I learned to recognize it in others work, I could see it in my own.

You're trying to find your own style of writing, so practice some free-writing in your spare time: sit down with whatever you use to write (computer, pen and paper, etc) and find a prompt and just write.
If you find yourself trying to sink into a favorite style of writing that you prefer reading, ask yourself if you like writing that way or reading that way (most of the time you like reading that way).
If you've found a style after practicing this but haven't honed it in yet (that takes time!) then read a lot of literature in that style, or just read more different styles of literature; either way, you'll be expanding your knowledge.
Above all: read and write religiously! If you keep it up, you'll find your style, or you'll find you can do multiple styles. Embrace the journey and you'll get to your destination easier, don't rush it! Happy writing:)

Fiction writing has a lot of stylistic differences from an category of formal writing, and is too individual to ALWAYS pinpoint "good style" versus bad style. However, even for someone strong in English, a book like "It was the best of sentences, it was the worst of sentences", by June Casagrande, can help you identify weaknesses in sentence writing.
You want to write strong, clear sentences, no matter what is your style is like, so that's a good start. After that, your style succeeds if your work interests and entertains readers, regardless of specifics. And you many not have a single style. I write in four genres and I have a different prose style for each genre. You'll find successful writers within one genre with distinctly different styles.
For many authors, their style is a natural narrative voice. So as I mentioned above use a resource like the one I mentioned above to check for weak sentences and learn how to improve them.
